# Ruby on Rails looks for css in assets instead of public/stylesheets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css

I am new to Ruby, using ruby 1.9.2P180 and Rails 3.1.0.rc2

I have "screen.css" in my_app_root/public/stylesheets/screen.css and in my application.html.erb

```
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'screen.css', :media => 'screen' %>
```

according to [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) it should work but my rails server says:

> Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
>   Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (0.0ms)
>   Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 3.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
>
> Started GET "/assets/screen.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-06-18 11:27:53 +1200
>   Served asset /screen.css - 404 Not Found  (2ms)  (pid 10966)
>
> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/screen.css"):

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong here?

Nothing, you are just using a default 3.1 install which uses the new sprockets-based asset pipeline.

put your stylesheets into /app/assets/stylesheets and use

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application.css' %>
```

in your views

the new pipeline takes all the stylesheets in that folder and automagically compiles them into a single file.

==

Alternatively, you can set turn the new pipline off in your application.rb with

```
config.assets.enabled = false
```

Comment: Sorry to hijack, but is it possible to specify different asset hosts per media type? (i.e. css.mydomain.com, js.mydomain.com, img.mydomain.com).  We use a setup like this with custom helpers, but just using assets would simplify things.

Comment: its rubyonrails, of course you can customize your hosts depending on content type.
Look into using a proc function.  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html  the example shown using the case of switching off ssl or not, but you can inspect the request to see what kind of file is being served and redirect to the right host...

Comment: Haha, "ruby on rails" != "of course you can customize", in my experience ;)  More the polar opposite.  Thanks for the link; very helpful! :)

Comment: @d11wtq: While it is true that rails (and ruby for that matter) prefer convention over configuration, I have yet to run into a situation where either a simple configuration or Class/Method override hasn't been an elegant solution. I will give you this much, not everything in Ruby/Rails is well documented outside of reading in-line comments in the source / via the rdocs.

Comment: Gotta agree that, while not always easy, you can customize EVERYTHING.  Sometimes it takes a monkey-patch, but at least the option is there.  Very refreshing coming from an ASP.NET background where Microsoft seals every class so if you don't like it, you're SOL...