# How to combine multiple css, js files and serve as one file in rails 3?

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have been trying to improve the page load time in Rails 3, I went through few [blogs](https://codedecoder.wordpress.com/2013/10/26/require_tree-require_self-in-asset_pipeline/) where I learned that I can include the **css**, **js** file names in **application.css** and **application.js** respectively.

For testing purpose I removed the files from the layout and included it in **application.css**, and then on page reload the **css** files didn't reload.

My current application.css file:

```
/*
* This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
* listed below.
*
* Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
* or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
*
* You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
* compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.

    *
    *= require_self
    *= require 'owl.carousel.min.css'
    *= require 'owl.carousel.min.css'
    *= require 'owl.theme.min.css'
    *= require "flag-sprites.min.css"
    *= require 'owl.transitions.min.css'
    */
```

**layout.html.erb:**

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application.css" %>
```

Comment: whats main problem?

Comment: By using the above code, the above mentioned css files do not load.

Comment: remove .css and dont use quot with `require`

Comment: I removed the quotes, and .css from the file names but doesn't help. What I want to achieve is have multiple files served as one file so that number of requests are reduced.

Comment: did you test it in production environment? `rails s -e producation`

Comment: No not in production environment? Isn't there a way to test it out in local first?

Comment: in `config/environment/development.rb` file add below line   `config.assets.debug = false`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116974/discussion-between-uzaif-and-sahil).

Comment: Yes it doesn't work it is not loading anything from the file application.css.

Comment: did you restart server?

Comment: try using  = require owl.carousel.min.css without single quote

Comment: @uzaif, yes I restarted server. Yes still not working, should I do any change in config files, or add a gem?

Comment: @chaitanya, I have removed the quotes as said by uzaif.

Comment: still not working?

Comment: do you have `uglifier` gem?

Comment: This works in rails 4 app by default but I am unable to get this work in Rails 3 app. Yes I have uglifier gem installed.

Comment: @Sahil just want to confirm if all your css files are under `app/assets/stylesheet` folder. Also just want to know if you see any errors in inspect element's console or maybe in network tab in browser.

Comment: Yes, all the css files are under assets/stylesheets. And in the network tab the application.css appears as it is with the require statements.

Comment: So, in browser inspect you are able to see this `*= require_self` statement as well? If you are seeing this, maybe it is not getting compile properly.

Comment: Yes, I get that. Is it supposed to be application.css or something else under stylesheets?

Comment: I don't know if this is the cause, please check if `sass-rails` gem is included in Gemfile, if not then try adding it and running bundle install. Then check by restarting the server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117010/discussion-between-t-d-ben-and-sahil).

Comment: @T.D.Ben, I am using import now, couldn't get require to work.  `sass-rails` is already installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
*= require_tree .
```

It will load all the css files inside **app/assets/stylesheet** so didn't need to mention each file name.

One more thing to Note is you need to restart the server after updating the application.css and application.js files. Hope this help.

Comment: I do not want to load the entire list there are more than 50 css files specific for each feature, controller. I am trying to optimize the code.

Comment: you can take a reference from [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422475/css-is-not-loading-in-app), there are multiple options, which you can try.